# How to use pause with openvar in a for loop

Tags: matlab

Using the following code:

```
tmpTable = table([1;2;3]);

for i = 1:5
    openvar tmpTable
    pause
end
```

When I run the for loop, all I get is a blank screen in the Variable Editor, except the dimensions of the table are displayed correctly. If I break from the for loop the table displays correctly.

[image]

My question is, how do I make this table display programmatically in the for loop, with a pause like command that allows me to inspect the table before moving onto the next one?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that `pause` is pausing the main MATLAB thread which is why you aren't seeing anything in the Variable Editor.  You have to make MATLAB enter debug mode if you want the main MATLAB thread to be free.... or of course break the loop as you have discovered.

A "hackish" way to get things going is to insert a [`keyboard`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html) statement instead of `pause` to force MATLAB to go into debug mode.  Once you're there, you'd have to use [`dbcont`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbcont.html) to continue onto the next iteration of the loop. This will make MATLAB enter debug mode again as the `keyboard` statement will be encountered again thus freeing the main thread. This repeats until the last iteration.

Therefore:

```
tmpTable = table([1;2;3]);

for i = 1:5
    openvar tmpTable
    keyboard; %// Change
end
```

You will then see `K>>` once you execute the first iteration of the loop when you look at the Command Prompt.  This signifies that you are in debug mode.  To proceed to the next iteration, type in `dbcont` in the Command Prompt and push <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  You can reuse the last command by pushing the Up arrow on your keyboard then push <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again and keep doing this until the last iteration of your loop. You will unfortunately have to click back in the Command Prompt as the focus will be placed on the Variable Editor before you enter in the command again.  If at any time you want to quit debug mode, use [`dbquit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbquit.html). This will terminate any code execution and bring you back to the Command Prompt.

This is the only way really to free up the main MATLAB thread at each iteration that I know of.